# Jquery and simple events

Tags: jquery, html

Why this code doesn't work? I checked it more than once but I cannot find the error! I'm just making some experiments with jquery and forms, but it seems like it don't want to work!

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Mini Blog</title>
<meta name="description" content="My Parse App">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/try.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="myID"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var postTitle = $("#postTitle").val();
  var postText = $("#postText").val();
  var sexAuthor = $("#sexAuthor").val();
  var cityAuthor = $("#cityAuthor").val();


  $("#button").click(function()
  {
      string = postTitle + postText + sexAuthor + cityAuthor;
      $("#visualize").text("a");
      alert('amama');
  });


 </script>


    <h2>Title:</h2> <br>
    <input type="text" id="postTitle"> <br>
    <h2>Contenuto del post:</h2>
    <input type="text" id="postText"> <br>
    <h2>Sei..?</h2>
    <input type="radio" id="sexAuthor" value="M"> M <br>
    <input type="radio" id="sexAuthor" value="F"> F <br>
    <h2>Vieni da:</h2> <br>
    <option> - Scegli città zì - </option>
    <select id="city">
        <option value="Roma"> Roma </option>
        <option value="Milano"> Milano </option>
    </select> <br>
    <button id="button"> Inviame zì! </button> <br>
    <p id="visualize"></p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Define "Does not work". What behaviour do you expect? How does this differ from what happens? What does the JavaScript error console say? Have you confirmed that all your files are loading by checking the developer tool's net tab in your browser?

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/) instead of using subheadings.

Comment: What does happen if you execute this code?

Comment: Well when I call the jquery's click() function by clicking the specific button it doesn't execute the function that should execute, the javascript error console doesn't tell me nothing, I coded it with bracket.js

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the DOM elements you want to access with javascript are loaded before you try to find them with js. You should place your scripts below the html, right in front of the `</body>` tag and wrap (most of) them in a document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var postTitle = $("#postTitle").val();
  var postText = $("#postText").val();
  var sexAuthor = $("#sexAuthor").val();
  var cityAuthor = $("#cityAuthor").val();


  $("#button").click(function()
  {
      var string = postTitle + postText + sexAuthor + cityAuthor;
      $("#visualize").text("a");
      alert('amama');
  });

});
```

Other issue, why you won't find the selected value of your radio later, is your html:

```
 <input type="radio" id="sexAuthor" value="M"> M <br>
 <input type="radio" id="sexAuthor" value="F"> F <br>
```

you can give an ID to exactly one DOM element. But you can change it to class and give them a name and check which one is selected:

```
alert($('input[name=sexAuthor]:checked').val());
```

and the **HTML**

```
<input type="radio" class="sexAuthor" name = "sexAuthor" value="M"> M <br>
<input type="radio" class="sexAuthor" name = "sexAuthor" value="F"> F <br>
<h2>Vieni da:</h2> <br>
```

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to make this code do? It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/4hvab248/2/

You might want to declare `var string = ...` in the `#button` click function just for cleanliness.

Comment: Yes, it is the problem because even if I replace the var string inside the button click function it doesn't work!